# Swift not converting specific values to a float

Tags: json, swift, floating-point, codable, jsondecoder

My code is not working to convert 1.1 to a float. It works to convert 1.0, 1.25, and 1.5 to floats but doesn't convert 1.1. I do not understand why this would happen as they are all decimals with very few digits of precision required. This is when decoding from a JSON.

The code in question:

```swift
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "moves", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let array = json as? [[String:Any]] {
            for dict in array {
                if let actionName = dict["name"] as? String,
                   let type = dict["type"] as? String,
                   let amt = dict["amtlost"] as? Int,
                   let val = dict["atkdefval"] as? Float,
                   let dtype = dict["element"] as? String,
                   let target = dict["target"] as? Bool,
                   let steal = dict["stealAmt"] as? Float{
                    
                    let cmove = Actions(name: actionName, type: type, amtlost: amt, atkdefval: val, damageType: dtype, target: target, stealAmt: steal)
                    self.moves.append(cmove)
                } else {
                    print(dict)
                    let val = dict["atkdefval"] as? Float
                    print(val)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error reading location JSON file: \(error)")
    }
} else {
    print("Could not read JSON")
}
print(self.moves.count)
for move in moves {
    print(move.name)
    print(move.atkdefval)
}
```

The JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Slash",
        "type": "phys",
        "amtlost": 0,
        "atkdefval": 1.5,
        "element": "slashing",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Punch",
        "type": "phys",
        "amtlost": 0,
        "atkdefval": 1.1,
        "element": "bludgeoning",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Magic Missile",
        "type": "magic",
        "amtlost": 2,
        "atkdefval": 1.75,
        "element": "force",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Block",
        "type": "defense",
        "amtlost": 0,
        "atkdefval": 1.5,
        "element": "bludgeoning",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Healing Word",
        "type": "healing",
        "amtlost": 2,
        "atkdefval": 1.25,
        "element": "light",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Shield",
        "type": "shield",
        "amtlost": 1,
        "atkdefval": 1.5,
        "element": "force",
        "target": false,
        "stealAmt": 0
    }
]
```

The class code (in case it helps):

```swift
enum ActionType:String, Codable{
    case phys = "phys"
    case magic = "magic"
    case defense = "defense"
    case healing = "healing"
    case shield = "shield"
}

enum DamageElement: String, Codable{
    case slash = "slashing"
    case pierce = "piercing"
    case bludgeon = "bludgeoning"
    case fire = "fire"
    case ice = "ice"
    case earth = "earth"
    case lightning = "lightning"
    case light = "light"
    case dark = "dark"
    case force = "force"
}

class Actions: Codable, Hashable, Equatable{
    var name: String
    var type: ActionType
    var amtlost: Int
    var atkdefval: Float
    var element: DamageElement
    var target: Bool // false is hp, true is mp
    var stealAmt: Float
    
    static func == (lhs: Actions, rhs: Actions) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { return hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))}
    
    init(){
        self.name = "punch"
        self.type = .phys
        self.amtlost = 0
        self.atkdefval = 4
        self.element = .bludgeon
        self.target = false
        self.stealAmt = 0
    }
    
    init(name: String, type: String, amtlost: Int, atkdefval: Float, damageType: String, target: Bool, stealAmt: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = ActionType(rawValue: type.lowercased())!
        self.amtlost = amtlost
        self.atkdefval = atkdefval
        self.element = DamageElement(rawValue: damageType.lowercased())!
        self.target = target
        self.stealAmt = stealAmt
    }
    
}
```

I tried to have it convert from a JSON dict as a float but it converted as `nil` instead of the expected 1.1. I tried converting it to a string from the JSON and to a float from there and it worked but it is confusing as to why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you call `print(type(of: dict["atkdefval"]))`?

Comment: Why are you using `JSONSerialization`  when your types conforms to `Codable`?

Comment: A possibly better way to deserialize the JSON is to write `let actions = try JSONDecoder().decode([Actions].self, from: data)`. Then `actions` will be an array of `Actions`.

Comment: From what I can see your types conform to `Codable`, so you should be able to use `JSONDecoder().decode(data, to: [Action].self)` instead of going through `JSONSerialization`.   That would simplify your code a lot, and I think would fix your problem.

Comment: Not relater to your question but why not simply  `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "moves", withExtension: "json")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JSONDecoder as McKinley describes, but the reason this fails for 1.1 is because the default internal type is Double and [the (rounded) Double value 1.1 doesn't fit in Float exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Consider:

```
import Foundation
NSNumber(1.1) as? Double    // 1.1
NSNumber(1.1) as? Float     // nil
NSNumber(1.5) as? Double    // 1.5
NSNumber(1.5) as? Float     // 1.5
```

1.5 can be expressed precisely in both Float and Double, so it converts.

JSONSerialization packs everything into an NSNumber, and that won't `as?` bridge to Float if it requires rounding. You could write it this way (but I don't recommend it):

```
    if let actionName = dict["name"] as? String,
       let type = dict["type"] as? String,
       let amt = dict["amtlost"] as? Int,
       let val = (dict["atkdefval"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue, // <==
       let dtype = dict["element"] as? String,
       let target = dict["target"] as? Bool,
       let steal = (dict["stealAmt"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue // <==
```

You can also fix this by using Double everywhere rather than Float, and you should do that anyway. [When in doubt, use Double in Swift for floating point.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics/#Floating-Point-Numbers)

But in addition, the better solution is to use JSONDecoder which avoids these subtle problems. Since all the types are already Decodable, your entire decoding logic can be replaced by:

```
self.moves = try JSONDecoder().decode([Actions].self, from: data)
```

Comment: NSNumber returns nil if you try to fetch a Float that can't be represented exactly? That's unexpected and a little bizarre, since **most** decimal values can't be represented exactly in binary floating point.  Thanks for the heads up, Rob!

Comment: NSNumber doesn't. Swift's `as?` cast to Float from an NSNumber that wraps a Double does. As a counter-example, an NSNumber that wraps a Float will `as?` cast to Float fine, because it will be exact: `NSNumber(value: Float(1.1)) as? Float`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Actions` class conforms to `Codable`, you can actually use the simpler `JSONDecoder` instead of `JSONSerialization`:

```
let listOfMoves = try JSONDecoder().decode([Actions].self, from: data)
self.moves.append(contentsOf: listOfMoves)
```

Then you don't have to worry about manually casting the entries of the dictionary to `Float`s and `Bool`s, etc., and then manually creating `Actions`. Instead, `JSONDecoder` will perform all that for you and spit out a nice array of `Actions` -- or throw an error if the JSON is improperly formatted.